# PHP minifiying HTML - skip reading JavaScript code and CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, preg-replace

Using the answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225351/how-to-minify-php-page-html-output), I am able to 'minify' html,

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {

    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',     // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',     // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s',         // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
        '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/' // Remove HTML comments
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1',
        ''
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

ob_start("sanitize_output");
```

But it breaks the html pages that have incline JavaScript code and CSS.

So how can I skip processing JavaScript code and CSS? Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Below is my HTML with JS code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
              type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
    
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var broadway = {
            info: '<strong>Chipotle on Broadway</strong><br>\
                        5224 N Broadway St<br> Chicago, IL 60640<br>\
                        <a href="#">Get Directions</a>',
            lat: -33.890542,
            long: 151.274856
        };
    
        var belmont = {
            info: '<strong>Chipotle on Belmont</strong><br>\
                        1025 W Belmont Ave<br> Chicago, IL 60657<br>\
                        <a href="#">Get Directions</a>',
            lat: -33.923036,
            long: 151.259052
        };
    
        var locations = [
          [broadway.info, broadway.lat, broadway.long, 0],
          [belmont.info, belmont.lat, belmont.long, 1],
          // [sheridan.info, sheridan.lat, sheridan.long, 2],
        ];
    
        // var locations = [
        //   ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
        //   ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
        //   // ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
        //   // ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
        //   // ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
        // ];
    
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":65},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":"50"},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":"30"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":"40"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffff00"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-97}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-100}]}]
        });
    
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    
        var marker, i;
    
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
          });
    
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you provide an example? I tried using [this](https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html) tool and `<script>` tags seems to work fine.

Comment: @fabriziomele see my edit above for the script that i have been using.

Comment: So in this case your code is "breaking" because the `//` starts a comment until the end of the line, and you're removing line breaks...

Answer (score 2):

> But it breaks the html pages that have incline JavaScript code and CSS.

Inline Javascript and CSS is generally considered bad practice for [performance](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2007/12/10/two-simple-rules-for-http-caching/) (not cacheable unless the entire HTML is cacheable), [maintainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710011/why-is-separation-of-javascript-and-html-a-good-practice) and [security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet).

You [can't parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Having said that I am a little curious as to how this breaks inline javascript and CSS.

You could run the HTML DOM parser over the code and remove comments and trim the leaf entities, but that's getting rather complicated.

Have you actually tried to measure the benefit of your efforts? If you are compressing the HTML, then the overall difference in size will not be that great. And bandwidth is not usually the most important determinant of perceived performance (1).

1) while I said that inlining is bad practice, *used appropriately* it can avoid the BIG performance hit of network latency

Comment: Personally I just do a global removal of `/\r?\n\t*/` and while the savings may be small, they add up fast. Definitely agree on the security point though.

Comment: it seem that compressing html actually slowing down the page loading a bit.

Comment: though, `Inline Javascript and CSS is generally considered bad practice` that is a bit of debate I guess - react & vue practise inline inline Javascript and CSS.

Comment: Something is very wrong with at least one end of your connection if compression has a measurable negative impact across a network with >10ms RTT (i.e. most of them)